# Restrict height on Android Recycleview xml

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a RecyclerView view that displays a list of items .On the top of the page is an action bar and at the bottom is a LinearLayout to enter text and a button(expands on click)with the area for list items in the middle. I am trying to limit the size of the RecyclerView height to the available height left over (below the Toolbar and above the the Linear Layout).

Unfortunately the the top and bottom items seem to go under the toolbar and layout at the bottom and cannot be seen. I managed to cheat the top by adding         `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize` but I know this is not the correct way of doing so. The scrolling is working as it should.

I can not understand why this is happening even with constraints set? How can I limit the recyclerview to the inside area?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="kevcon.ie.cloaked.SendMessage">

<!-- Might remove to suit api level-->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_inbox_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_chatbox"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGrey"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout_chatbox"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_toolbar" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGrey"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:hint="@string/send_message_hint"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_sms_send"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:background="@color/colorAccent"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/send_button_text"
        android:textSize="14sp"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try it like below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

  <!-- Might remove to suit api level-->
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_inbox_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"


    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_toolbar"
    />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/mView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout_chatbox"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />


  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkGray"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edit_message"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:hint="@string/terms_service"
      android:maxLines="6"/>

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_sms_send"
      android:layout_width="64dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:background="@color/colorAccent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/send"
      android:textSize="14sp"

      />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank for reply, I tried that and got `cannot resolve symbol tools:listitem="@layout/row_bank_item" ` , so I removed that line as I am unsure what its suppose to do but still have the same problem last item in the recycleview is half covered by LinearLayout and View

Comment: This solved it perfectly ,I just need to add a bit of spacing between Linearlayout now thank you